# Can I use negative voltage generator TC7660 as voltage doubler to drive LED of MAXIM30101 oximeter IC?

Tags: multiplier, charge-pump, voltage-doubler

I am trying to use two AAA battery to generate two power supplies,

1. 1.8V(via regulator AM1117)
2. 5-6V to drive LED (using voltage doubler TC7660).

Both these voltage is requirement of Oximeter sensor MX30101/MX30102.

Below is the schematic

[image]

I am using negative voltage out of TC7660, and use it as a ground input the LED supply(PGND) of IC MAXIM30101, this would generate equivalent voltage of 3V*2 =6V.

From datasheet of MAXIM30101(https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX30101.pdf) it is showing different grounds for GND and PGND, but I still have doubt how is it different than having actual 6V power.

So can we safely use negative voltage generator as a voltage doubler supply power to LED driver?

Comment: "**Absolute Maximum Ratings**
... 
**GND to PGND**....................................................... **-0.3V to +0.3V**"

Comment: @BruceAbbott Awesome, now explain how OP can accept your answer.

Comment: @BruceAbbott - Hi, As commented, that seems more of an answer than one of the [allowed uses of a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) i.e. it states the source of the the problem, rather than just helping the OP to improve the question. Please can you consider moving that into a real answer (even a short one) so that it doesn't get lost if the comment gets flagged etc.? Also as commented, an answer-in-a-comment can't be accepted, it also isn't indexed in the site search, isn't included in the count of answers, etc etc. Thanks for understanding :-)

Answer (score 1):

> So can we safely use negative voltage generator as a voltage doubler supply power to LED driver?

No, they share the same reference (disregarding the effect of LED currents). Providing a negative voltage at PGND is not the reason the IC provides different power connections for the LEDs (also don't just short GND and PGND pins). You must provide a clean path for the regulated voltage used in the sensitive part of the circuit and another path for the higher current (and voltage) required by the LEDs. The two parts interface internally:

[image]

And there is another problem: AM1117-1.8 needs at least 3.3 V at its input:

[image]

If you need to use the TC7660 you can double the AAA voltage (minus two  diodes voltage drops) and connect this unregulated voltage to the LEDs if the ripple does not affect the measurement.

[image]

This higher voltage could be the input for the linear 1.8 V (low current) voltage regulator.

This is the voltage doubler configuration (not the "*Negative Converter*"):

[image]

*Source: all images from the respective datasheets*